# Bootstrap 3 - mobile menu on resized desktop view still fires onhover, not the mobile onclick

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, desktop

I have a bootstrap menu, and the desktop menu works fine on desktops (onHover) and the mobile menu works fine on mobile (onClick).  The problem I have is when a user resizes a desktop window to the mobile break point, the collapsed mobile menu still operates onHover and not onClick on the desktop.  This makes it tricky to navigate to the bottom menu links in the menu on a desktop if a user has resized to a smaller window.

My HTML

```
<div class="main-frame">
    <div class="row-fluid header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid nav-header">
                <div class="row-fluid header-left">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/images/logo.jpg" alt=""></a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid header-right">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $cartUrl; ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/images/cart-icon.png" alt=""> <?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a></li>
                        <li><div id="google_translate_element"></div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                              new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'es,it,no'}, 'google_translate_element');
                            }
                            </script>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="search-box">
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid nav-bar">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'top-navigation', 'menu_class' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu', 'container' => '',)); ?>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Some of the jQuery being loaded from script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//Bootstrap fix for responsive mobile menu height
jQuery(".navbar-collapse").css({ maxHeight: jQuery(window).height() - jQuery(".navbar-header").height() + "px" });    

//onHover 
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('a[href="#"]').on("click", function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
});
jQuery("#menu li ul.sub-menu li").each(function(a) {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("menu-item-has-children")) {
        jQuery(this).children("a").removeAttr("href");
        jQuery(this).children("a").css("cursor", "pointer");
    }
});
var a = jQuery(window).width();
jQuery("ul.sub-menu").hide();
jQuery("ul#menu > li, ul.sub-menu > li").hover(function() {
    if (a > 767) {
        console.log("erer");
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("top-parent-menu")) jQuery(this).find("ul > li:first").addClass("active");
    }
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
    if (a > 767) if (jQuery(this).find("ul li:first").children("ul").length > 0) jQuery(this).find("ul li:first ul.sub-menu").show();
    if (jQuery("> ul.sub-menu", this).length > 0) jQuery("> ul.sub-menu", this).stop().show();
}, function() {
    if (jQuery("> ul.sub-menu", this).length > 0) jQuery("> ul.sub-menu", this).stop().hide();
});
});

var id;
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
clearTimeout(id);
id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);

});

function doneResizing(){
jQuery(".navbar-collapse").css({ maxHeight: jQuery(window).height() - jQuery(".navbar-header").height() + "px" });
}
```

Comment: I've fixed half the issue, I've created a resize event based on another solution on the forum.  I just refire the same jQuery code that fixes the mobile height issue for bootstrap at the end of a window resize function.  At least now you can scroll down the menu on a small screen on a desktop.  I've updated the above jQuery with the code.

Comment: The remaining issue is that on a desktop when using the collapsed mobile view, the onHover code is still active instead of onClick.  I'll probably have to fire another line of jQuery on that resize event